# Calling another javascript function after pushing data from db into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this code which is retrieve the data from db and then push into an array in my angularJS script

```
if(type == 'createSupplierInvoice'){
            vm.data.organization = {};
            vm.data.organization.selected = {
                name: result.data.name,
                id: result.data.organization_id
            } 
            vm.data.ship_request_id = result.data.ship_request_id;
            vm.data.terms = Number(result.data.payment_terms);  
            if(result.products.length > 0){
                for(var i = 0;i<result.products.length;i++){
                    vm.products.push({
                        id: result.products[i].id,
                        product_id: result.products[i].ship_product_id,
                        code : result.products[i].ship_product_code,
                        description : result.products[i].ship_product_description,
                        request_quotation_detail_id : result.products[i].ship_request_quotation_detail_id,
                        qty : result.products[i].qty,
                        price : result.products[i].price,
                        total_price : result.products[i].total_price,
                        remarks : result.products[i].remarks,
                        temp_tax : 0,
                        temp_total: 0,
                        temp_subtotal: 0,
                    });
                }
            }
            for(var d = 0; d < vm.products.length; d++){
                calculateTotal(vm.products[d]);  
                console.log(vm.products[d]);
            }
        }
```

here is my calculateTotal function

```
function calculateTotal(items){
    console.log(items);
    var tax            = parseFloat(vm.data.tax_percentage);
    var qty            = parseFloat(items.qty);
    var price          = parseFloat(items.price);
    var temp_total     = parseFloat(0), temp_subtotal  = parseFloat(0);

    temp_subtotal += (qty * price);
    tax        = parseFloat(temp_subtotal * (vm.data.tax_percentage * 1) / 100);
    temp_total    += parseFloat(temp_subtotal + tax);

    items.temp_tax      = parseFloat(tax);
    items.temp_subtotal = parseFloat(temp_subtotal);
    items.temp_total    = parseFloat(temp_total);

    setTotal();
}
function setTotal(){
    var calculated_tax = parseFloat(0), calculated_subtotal = parseFloat(0), calculated_total = parseFloat(0);
    for(var i = 0; i < vm.products.length; i++){
        calculated_tax      += parseFloat(vm.products[i].temp_tax);
        calculated_subtotal += parseFloat(vm.products[i].temp_subtotal);
        calculated_total    += parseFloat(vm.products[i].temp_total);
    }
    vm.data.total_tax  = parseFloat(calculated_tax).toFixed(2);
    vm.data.subtotal   = parseFloat(calculated_subtotal).toFixed(2);
    vm.data.grandtotal = parseFloat(calculated_total).toFixed(2);
}
```

I tested the code by putting console.log(items) inside the calculateTotal function, but it never fire. The function is not being called in array looping after it has been pushed by data from db.

However, the console.log(vm.products[d]) Is working. It shows me correct data. If i copy paste all the code inside those 2 functions(calculateTotal and setTotal), it is working too. I don't know why the calculateTotal function is not being fired if I directly call it inside the looping. Can somebody guide me ??

Thank you so much..

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no sir.. totally no error. all is working fine

Answer (score 0):

At which point have you declared your function? Also is you function attached to the scope? If you call a function before declaring that would give issues i guess.

I tried a sample code, working fine for me.

```
 var a=[
{'name':'jack','age':23},
{'name':'jones','age':24}
]

var calculateTotal= function(items){
  console.log(items);
}

for(var d = 0; d < a.length; d++){
  calculateTotal(a[d].name);
  console.log(a[d].name);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/we5pg2d1/)

Comment: You can declare the function after you use it, because function declaration are hoisted to the beginning of the function